# RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED not received on Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm rebooting the phone and I expect a log message. I've registered the `BroadcastReceiver` in `Androidmanifest`, but no message is being received. What am I Missing?

**androidmanifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <!-- Receives an event when the device has completed a reboot -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**BootReceiver:**

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context, p1: Intent) {
        Log.i("BootReceiver", "Boot event received")
    }
}
```

When I filter in the logging for "boot" I see several other apps logging the event, but not my own App:

```
I/NU.LockBootCompleteReceiver: onReceive : Intent { act=android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x89000010 cmp=com.samsung.android.app.telephonyui/.netsettings.ui.receiver.LockBootCompleteReceiver (has extras) }
I/BCL@CoreSvc: (CoreServiceComponentEnabler) updateComponent() : class com.samsung.android.bixby.receiver.token.BootCompleteReceiver | 2
I/BCL@CoreSvc: (CoreServiceComponentEnabler) updateComponent() : class com.samsung.android.bixby.receiver.token.LazyBootCompleteReceiver | 1
I/CIDManager: [onReceive(BootReceiver.java:20)] onReceive: android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED
I/ActivityManager: Start proc 7201:com.samsung.android.game.gametools/u0a79 for broadcast {com.samsung.android.game.gametools/com.samsung.android.game.gametools.floatingui.receiver.GameBoosterBootCompleteReceiver}
I/GameTools: BootCompleteReceiver already enabled.
I/GameTools: GameBoosterBootCompleteReceiver: onReceive: Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED
I/GameTools: GameBoosterBootCompleteReceiver: clear runtime settings on boot complete.
I/GameTools: GameBoosterBootCompleteReceiver: register Intent.ACTION_USER_UNLOCKED
I/GameTools: GameBoosterBootCompleteReceiver: register Intent.ACTION_USER_UNLOCKED via EventDelegationManager
I/ORC/FbeBootReceiver: onReceive : android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED
I/ORC/FbeBootReceiver: FBE islocked : true
I/CS/MsgFMMReceiverService: PCW LOCK. handlePCWLockMessage. LockedBootComplete : true
I/CS/xmsFbeJobService: onLockedBootCompleted()
I/ORC/FbeMigrationJobService: onLockedBootCompleted()
I/StateUtils: isDirectBootMode On : true
I/PackageManager: !@Start postBootUpdate
I/PackageManager: !@Finish postBootUpdate dexopted: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

After Android3.1, in order to strengthen the security control, the system is in the `stopped state` after the application is installed or is forced to close in the (settings) application management. In this state, no broadcast can be received unless the broadcast has the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag , and by default all system broadcasts are FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES, so there is no way to self-start through system broadcasts.

Therefore, after installing the application, you must first start the application yourself so that it is not in the stopped state before you can receive the broadcast.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```xml
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Categories are normally only used on activities, not broadcasts.

Answer (score -1):

The code above is working fine.
I have checked on device ->
google pixel 4a, os 12
mi a1, os 11

i am able to see logs every time i reboot my device.
Try changing your device and test.

check the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```